# Adjusting according to screen size

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I created an application in Asp.net framework 4.0

The application's main layout(UI) differ in its height and width in different browsers.

How can I make my application's UI adjust automatically according to resolution of the browser? I am writing functions using JQUERY. Is there any way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at CSS? What are the devices/browsers you wish to support ?

Comment: I am creating a fully responsive application. It should support all the devices and browsers which supports CSS3 and HTML5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call window resize event

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var currentWindowHeight = $(window).height();
    var currentWindowWidth = $(window).width();

    ...
});
```

then you can adjust css with jquery.